# у меня не выполняется print внутри условия

Tags: python

почему при запуске приведённого ниже кода система ничего не выводит в консоль, и как это исправить?

```
for N in range(1, 100):
    z = N - (N % 4)
    v = bin(z)[:2]
    i = v.count('1')
    t = v + str(i % 2)
    G = v.count('1')
    T = v+str(G % 2)
    R = int(T, 2)
    if R > 100:
        print(R)
        break
```

Comment: Код в вопросе нужно публиковать текстом, а не картинкой. Чтобы что-то выводилось, нужно убрать срез[:2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В команде

```
v = bin(z)[:2]
```

вы очевидно хотели избавиться от символов `0b` в начале бинарного числа, но вместо того вы избавились от **остальных** символов, т.е. всех бинарных цифр.

Примените вместо того срез `[2:]`:

```
v = bin(z)[2:]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1, 100):
    z = i - (i%4)
    v = bin(z)[2:]
    j = v.count("1")
    t = v + str(j % 2)
    g = v.count("1")
    l = v+str(g % 2)
    r = int(l, 2)
    if r > 100:
       print(r)
       break
```